# No driver detected for Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02) card

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel-graphics, xrandr, intel-nuc

There is a problem with my display ouput.

The Asus ZenScreen monitor cannot detect a signal after switching off and on again. I will have to hibernate the machine before the display can work again.

Apparently, the system is unable to detect the `xrandr` connection type for my display:

```bsh
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x55a) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

possibly due to a lack of driver for my graphics card:

```bsh
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: N/A 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3
```

It says here that a kernel upgrade is needed,

```bsh
intel_gpu_top
Failed to detect engines! (No such file or directory)
(Kernel 4.16 or newer is required for i915 PMU support.)
```

But my kernel version is clearly newer than the 4.16 requirement.

```bsh
uname -r
5.11.0-27-generic
```

Assuming the driver is already installed with the kernel, though I can select intel as my driver,

```bsh
prime-select query
intel
```

it is apparent the Intel UHD Graphics card cannot detect any compatible driver in the kernel. (No `Kernel driver in use` in the output below.)

```bsh
lspci -k
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
    DeviceName:  GPU
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Can someone diagnose what's the issue over here?

The `xrandr` command had been working properly with the same setup before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found out what's wrong. Here's what I did:

```bsh
sudo nvim /etc/default/grub
```

Change this line:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

to this:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Then:

```bsh
sudo update-grub
```

And the display is working properly again.

```bsh
inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

```bsh
lspci -k
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
    DeviceName:  GPU
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: So you just undid what you you did before that **caused** the problem? This is likely a misunderstanding of what `nomodeset` does and its purpose as a **temporary** workaround to have video until the user installs some required proprietary drivers - currently only applicable to Nvidia, but you have Intel??? -, not a "solution" for anything. It shoud be noted that this kernel parameter doesn't appear *ex nihilo*, it is **always** added by users.

Comment: I modified the settings to `nomodeset` before to solve the problem of not reaching the login screen upon reboot. I wasn't aware of any side-effects of this setting at that time.

Comment: Things seem to be working fine after the reset. @ChanganAuto, I would appreciate a *proper* solution or an explanation for what `nomodeset` does to cause the problem above.

Comment: `nomodeset` (No Mode Set) is used to override any graphics driver thus forcing a fallback standard VESA graphics mode, typically low resolution, that should be supported by any graphics subsystem in any circumstance. As explained above it's or was typically used when a brand new Nvidia chipset has no proper support by the open-source alternative `nouveau` driver and the default in Ubuntu. However, since a few releases ago users have the option to automatically install Nvidia proprietary driver thus not requiring the `nomodeset` workaround.

Comment: I was merely following the instructions over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) to solve the blank screen problem.